# Confused about torch.nn.Sequential

Tags: python, pytorch

Supposing we want to add a new layer, say a linear layer, to the end of the classifier of another model, such as VGG16, why exactly do these two implementations lead to different results? More specifically, I don't understand why the first implementation produces 2 classfiers:

```
vgg = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
vgg.classifer=nn.Sequential(vgg.classifier, nn.Linear(4096,300))
print(vgg)
```

output:

```
    VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace)
    (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): ReLU(inplace)
    (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace)
    (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (25): ReLU(inplace)
    (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (27): ReLU(inplace)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace)
    (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
    (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
  (classifer): Sequential(
    (0): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (1): ReLU(inplace)
      (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (4): ReLU(inplace)
      (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
    )
    (1): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=300, bias=True)
  )
)
```

implementation2:

```
vgg = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
vgg=nn.Sequential(vgg, nn.Linear(4096,300))
print(vgg)
```

output:

```
Sequential(
  (0): VGG(
    (features): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (1): ReLU(inplace)
      (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (3): ReLU(inplace)
      (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (6): ReLU(inplace)
      (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (8): ReLU(inplace)
      (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (11): ReLU(inplace)
      (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (13): ReLU(inplace)
      (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (15): ReLU(inplace)
      (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (18): ReLU(inplace)
      (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (20): ReLU(inplace)
      (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (22): ReLU(inplace)
      (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (25): ReLU(inplace)
      (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (27): ReLU(inplace)
      (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (29): ReLU(inplace)
      (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    )
    (classifier): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=25088, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (1): ReLU(inplace)
      (2): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=True)
      (4): ReLU(inplace)
      (5): Dropout(p=0.5)
      (6): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
    )
  )
  (1): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=300, bias=True)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a syntax error in the spelling of *classifier*. You have written it as

```
vgg.classifer=nn.Sequential(vgg.classifier, nn.Linear(4096,300))
```

Note the missing `i` after `f` in `classifier` on LHS. So, you're inadvertently creating a new group of layers named `classifer` by this line.

---

**After correction:**

```
vgg.classifier=nn.Sequential(vgg.classifier, nn.Linear(4096,300))
```

Moreover, in the first example, you're replacing the existing `classifier` layer *with* a sequential network having `classifier` portion of original vgg and `Linear` layer as the last layer.

In the second example, you're recreating the variable `vgg` *with* a new sequential network which contains the original vgg network with the addition of `Linear` layer as the last layer.

```
vgg=nn.Sequential(vgg, nn.Linear(4096,300))
```

Note the difference between the above two.

Comment: Lol thanks a lot, can't believe I was struggling so hard all for a syntax error :D Also, I don't quite understand the difference between putting the last layer in the classifier or at the top of the whole network...both produce the same results after running the forward function right?

Comment: @GhazalSahebzamani Yes, both yield the same result. I wanted to clarify the difference between the code. But note that the last layer of original vgg has `out_features` 1000 but the `Linear` layer you added has 4096 `in_features`. You'd want to change that.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to help @GhazalSahebzamani. You can accept the answer if your problem is solved :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with this place... how can I do that?

Comment: @GhazalSahebzamani To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. It'll turn green once you accept the answer.